# The Darboux vector is defined by $D = \tau T + \kappa B$. Show that $T' = D \times T$

Tags: differential-geometry, cross-product

> The **Darboux Vector** is defined as $D = \tau T + \kappa B$. Show that for a unit speed curve
>
> $$T' = D \times T  \hspace{1cm} ... $$

Here, the $...$ represents the fact that there are a few more equations I need to show, but I think with the hints for this first one, I can do the rest. For a space curve $\gamma$, $T$ is the unit tangent, i.e $T = \frac{\gamma'}{|\gamma'|}$. If $P$ is the principal normal, i.e $P = \frac{T'}{|T'|}$, then $B$ is the Binormal, i.e $B = T \times P$. $\tau$ is the torsion and $\kappa$ is the curvature.

I know that as its unit speed, $|\gamma ' | = 1$. The method I want to show is that, I know from the Serret-Frenet equations that $T' = \kappa P$, where $P$ is the principal normal, i.e $P = \frac{T'}{|T'|}$. So I want to show that $D \times T = \kappa P$, but the bit I am stuck on is how to do the cross product of $(\tau T + \kappa B) \times \gamma'$.

I could use the fact that $T = P \times B$, but even then, I wouldn't know how to do $D \times (P \times B)$.

Can someone give me some tips please. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$(\tau T + \kappa B) \times T= \kappa B \times T = \kappa P$$

Comment: How can I tell the directions of these vectors like this? Or is it just the general rule that $T$ and $\gamma'$ are in the same direction due to the fact that they are in a SF basis?

Comment: You can tell by the way you define $T$. It is just $\gamma^{\prime}$ divided by its lenght. So $T$ is by definition a unit vector in the direction of $\gamma^{\prime}$.

Comment: @PAD why $\kappa B \times T = \kappa P$ Can you be more detailed?

Comment: @The Martian : $T,N,B$ is an orthornormal system (I use here N instead of P)